How to change font sizes for elements in shadcn calendar
I'm trying to change the font sizes for my Calendar component so that it is more readable to users, but the font size of the month header (e.g. "August 2024") refuses to change. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?
This is my code
<div className="flex-1 h-[500px] w-full my-4">
          <Calendar
            mode="single"
            selected={date}
            onSelect={setDate}
            onDayClick={(date) => {
              console.log("Day Clicked", date);
            
            }}
            className="rounded-md border w-full h-full flex"
            classNames={{
              months:
                "flex w-full flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0 flex-1",
              month: "space-y-4 w-full flex flex-col",
              table: "w-full h-full border-collapse space-y-1",
              head_row: "",
              row: "w-full mt-2 bg-transparent",
              day: "text-lg w-16 h-16 rounded-sm",
            }}
          />
        </div>
...

Current output:

Expected output:

I've tried to modify the styles values under the classNames attribute, but have only been able to modify the styles for the day cells. I've also attempted to use the method detailed here, but my CSS is getting overridden by something else, or it does not load

Update your code as below:
<div className="flex-1 h-[500px] w-full my-4">
  <Calendar
    mode="single"
    selected={date}
    onSelect={setDate}
    onDayClick={(date) => {
      console.log("Day Clicked", date);
    }}
    className="flex w-full h-full border rounded-md"
    classNames={{
      months:
        "flex w-full flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-x-4 sm:space-y-0 flex-1",
      month: "space-y-4 w-full flex flex-col",
      table: "w-full h-full border-collapse space-y-1",
      caption_label: "text-lg", // change font size as per your need
      row: "w-full mt-2 bg-transparent",
      day: "text-lg w-16 h-16 rounded-sm",
    }}
  />
</div>

Changes: You need to use caption_label key
